# Can I get notified when user's phone number changed through change notification/webhook？

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I was researching how to get notified when a selected user's attribute changed, like a phone number or email, through a change notification.

When looking into the Microsoft graph API document, I see user changes can be notified. I want to know if I can use some filter to only monitor one of user's attribute changes？

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/webhooks?view=graph-rest-1.0
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/webhooks

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

To check the user property change or a particular Attributes as mentioned in the document here, you can use this
[image]

For more information on notification please refer: Microsoft Graph change notifications

hope this helps.